# How to skip repeated ids from table and select remains using linq

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

In a table i have the following,

GroupId
3786
3787
3788
3788

So i need to take 3786, 3787 id's only. If i use `distinct()` it will take 3788 also. I don't know which method should use in linq.

```
IQueryable<Sub> subDetails=
            from carSub in this.UnitOfWork.Repository<CarSub>().Queryable()
                //from pcs in carSub.ConfirmedCarrier.CarrierCandidate.ProductCarrierScores
            join p in this.UnitOfWork.Repository<ProductGroup>().Queryable() on carSub.Submission.PlacementID equals p.PlacementID
            join pg in this.UnitOfWork.Repository<ProductGroupMember>().Queryable() on p.ProductGroupID equals pg.ProductGroupID
            join pcs in this.UnitOfWork.Repository<ProductCarrierScore>().Queryable() on p.ProductGroupID equals pg.ProductGroupID
```

inside of that JOIN `join pcs in this.UnitOfWork.Repository<ProductCarrierScore>().Queryable() on p.ProductGroupID equals pg.ProductGroupID` here only i have to use this

pg means ProductGroupMember. in that Member i have to pass the only not repeated values only. Please guide me. I am stuck very much

Comment: so if ids are like `1 2 3 3 4 5 6 6 7`, do you want to take `4 5 6 6 7` or `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`, or `1 2 4 5 7`?

Answer (score 2):

i would make it like this:

1. Group them by `GroupId`;
2. Get only those which have 1 element in group;

The code will look like this:
`var groupIds = subDetails.GroupBy(x=>x.GroupId).Where(x=>x.Count()==1).Select(x=>x.Key)`

P.S. There might be some other faster solutions for this, but this is what came to mind first.

Answer (score 1):

You can group by, then narrow down the results to items with count less than 2

For example,

```
var ids = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 2, 5, 3, 4};

var itemsNotDuplicate = ids.GroupBy(f => f, t => t, 
          (k, items) => new {val = k, count = items.Count()}).Where(g => g.count < 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also you TakeWith

```
var list = new List<int> { 3786, 3787, 3788, 3788};
var onlyOne=list.TakeWhile(t=> list.Count(l=>l==t)==1);
```

its a similar approach to using GroupBy, but you only need to use a single lambda expression.